# I put \pgfresetboundingbox after \clip, what should the bounding box be?

Tags: tikz-pgf, bounding-box, path-clipping

## Short question

After a `\clip` and a `\pgfresetboundingbox`, the bounding box is permanently `(0,0)rectangle(0,0)`. How can I turn on the bounding-box calculation and obtain a fairly small bounding box?

## The story

The example below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikz{
    \clip circle(10);
    \pgfresetboundingbox
    \fill circle(10);
%   \useasboundingbox(-10,-10)(10,10); % makes no difference
}

\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

where the rectangle is the US-letter paper from `article` and the center of the circle is approximately the starting point of normal documents. This shows that `\pgfresetboundingbox` resets the bounding box, as expected. However, a normal path does not *repair* it. Neither does an explicit `\useasboundingbox`.

The question is:

> After a `\clip` and a `\pgfresetboundingbox`,
>   How can I **turn on** the calculation of bounding box?

Recall that in everyday usage, the code with `\pgfresetboundingbox` will always give a smaller or equal bounding box than that without `\pgfresetboundingbox`. In the case above, it does give me a smaller bounding box. (just too small)

Therefore I expect that if somehow we can turn the calculation on, it should not give a bounding box that is larger than that without `\pgfresetboundingbox`.

In other words,

> After a `\clip` and a `\pgfresetboundingbox`,
>   How can I **turn on** the calculation of bounding box
>   such that it is the *smallest*  but contains everything visible?

```
\tikz{
    \clip(5,0)--(-4,-4)--(0,5)--cycle;
    \pgfresetboundingbox
    \fill(-5,0)--(4,4)--(0,-5)--cycle;
}
```

should give me

[image]

where the hidden parts are

[image]

## Possible application

The following code generate bad right border. (beacuse of the control point)

```
\tikz{
    \fill(0,-1)..controls(10,0)..(0,1);
}
```

[image]

It would be good if we can apply some clipping **only** on right border.

```
% Caution! imaginary code
\tikz[clip right at x=7]{
    \fill(0,-1)..controls(10,0)..(0,1);
}
```

[image]

which is implemented by inserting

```
    \clip(-\maxdimen,-\maxdimen)rectangle(7,\maxdimen);
    \pgfresetboundingbox
```

## Remark

If two clippings are issued consecutively, the bounding box should be even smaller.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like the actual outcome of your code.

Comment: What is the relation between the first and the second figure you posted?

Comment: @Alenanno Second one is the desired usecase of the question. First one is the test MWE

Comment: @percusse I finishing updating packages and the first figure is the exact output. I am now editing my question to make it more friendly.

Answer (score 1):

I see you have added some details to your question, but I had already done the first part, so I'll post it. I can see that I might have to change something for you to "reuse" the clipping, at first the question seemed to imply it was a one-time thing.

### Output

> **Showing shapes**

[image]

> **Hidden**

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\tikz{
    \useasboundingbox(-10,-10)(10,10);
    \node[
        anchor=east, %fill=yellow, 
        minimum height=25cm, minimum width=5cm,
        isosceles triangle, rotate=45, 
        ] (trifill) at (current bounding box.north east) {};
        \node[
        anchor=east, %draw, dashed, 
        minimum height=25cm, minimum width=5cm,
        isosceles triangle, rotate=225
        ] (tridashed) at (current bounding box.south west) {};

\begin{scope}
    \clip (trifill.apex) foreach \i in {left corner, right corner} {--(trifill.\i)} --cycle;
    \clip (tridashed.apex) foreach \i in {left corner, right corner} {--(tridashed.\i)} --cycle;
    \fill[black] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{scope}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is a good idea to achieve `\fill` by a second `\clip`. But sadly this does not apply to `\draw`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Symbol1 Mmh not sure what you're referring to. As in using `\draw` instead of `\fill`?

Comment: Yes: what if I replace `\fill(-5,0)--(4,4)--(0,-5)--cycle;` by `\draw(-5,0)--(4,4)--(0,-5)--cycle;`